# Force browser traffic through HTTP/HTTPS Proxy on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, wfp

There are many ways to force browsers to use a proxy, but none so far has convinced me.

1. Set a global proxy on the internet settings.
   While this works in most cases (IE, Edge, Chrome) it may not work with FireFox if the default settings is "use no proxy".

it is thus is not a very efficient way of doing it.

2. Using LSP (Layered Service Provider), this is deprecated.
3. Using WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) or Windivert, while being simply done for non-SSL traffic, it becomes more difficult with HTTPS traffic as the headers are encrypted. It is then necessary to capture and map DNS queries as well. It possible but far to be a neat solution.
4. Using GPO (Group Policy), after a few tests with group policy I did not achieve to force the traffic through a proxy.
5. Using a [Registry Key](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/221139-46-make-proxy-settings-machine-rather-user) also did not succeed.
6. Using WPAD configuration, but that is the same as point 1.

I also attempted to test some software like Proxifier and FreeCap which none seemed to be working (Looks like old projects and probably doesn't support recent windows platform).

Is there other way than the ones listed above for windows ? I believe there is but struggle to find.

---

Edit:
My searches had led me to **Kernel Network Redirector Driver Components**, but not sure how this can be used to force traffic into a proxy.

Comment: It is a nice summary of options. The WFP option should work. You don't need to tweak DNS traffic, unless you want to implement deep packet inspection (i.e. decrypt and re-encrypt HTTPS traffic with a fake SSL cert).

Comment: We also need to handle DNS traffic as the goal is to go through restrictive firewall that blocks some website

Comment: @Damien Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @OneAndOnly it dates a bit and don't remember very well. If I remember, there was no "clean" way to do it...